Smoothen the elevation graph in leaflet
I'm developing this map using Leaflet + leaflet-elevation.js.
On the bottom of the page it's showing the graph correctly but it looks like it has a dot for every single point in the GPX file.
Is there a way to "smoothen" the graph?
I tried changing the xTicks option, setting it to a lower number (100 ATM) but it doesn't seem to have any effect.
https://www.itinerarium.it/newmap/

To smooth the elevation graph in a Leaflet map using leaflet-elevation.js, you can sample the GPX track data before processing it with the plugin. This involves selecting every nth point from the track to reduce the overall number of points plotted on the graph, thereby achieving a smoother appearance.
function sampleData(gpxPoints, sampleRate) {
    let sampledPoints = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < gpxPoints.length; i += sampleRate) {
        sampledPoints.push(gpxPoints[i]);
    }
    return sampledPoints;
}

// Example usage
let gpxData = /* your GPX data here */;
let sampleRate = 10; // Adjust based on desired smoothing level
let smoothedData = sampleData(gpxData, sampleRate);

// Then, use smoothedData with leaflet-elevation.js

This approach selects a subset of points from the GPX track data, reducing the granularity of the graph and resulting in a smoother elevation profile.
You can click here for github and here for stack overflow sources that i used

Steps to Smoothen the Graph

Modify the Interpolation Method in the d3.js Area Function:
Change the interpolation method from curveLinear to curveNatural.

Reduce the Number of Points in the Path:
Implement a technique to downsample the data by selecting fewer points.


Rough Overview

Modify the Interpolation Method:

Locate the file responsible for defining the D3.js area chart (d3.js within the src/components directory). Change the Area function and update its configuration to use curveNatural for interpolation instead of curveLinear. Check the d3 interpolation options ...

Rebuild the Bundle:

After making the changes to the interpolation method, rebuild the project to generate the updated bundle with the correct interpolation method (npm build). Use the newly built bundle in your project to see the smoothed graph with the reduced number of points. -> make sure you have also included all the helpers etc.

Reduce the Number of Points:

Identify where the data is processed before being used to generate the path for the area chart (either in the source code or as your input). Apply a downsampling method to the dataset, such as picking every nth point, to reduce the total number of points used in the graph. This simplification helps to create a smoother appearance by reducing the density of plotted points.
